# Manpulating list of dicts

Tags: python

When I attempt to append a new dict, the new dict always overwrites the old one. I've tried multiple approaches, but nothing seems to work.

I think what I need to be doing is adding something like "for transaction_dict in transactions:" but nothing happens when I run the function. Could someone please help me understand what I'm not seeing?

```
def transaction():
  global transactions
  transactions = []
  transaction_dict = {}
  transactions.append(
    {'transaction_record':len(transactions)+1,
    'transaction_name': input('Transaction Name: '),
    'amount':float(input('Amount: ')),
    'date':'{:%A, %b %d, %Y}'.format(date.today()),
    'budget':input('Which budget? ')
    })
transaction()
```

Edit - Thank you @Igor and @Putnam! Resulting code works great (moving transactions outside of the function and NOT using global transactions, as well as removing the pointless dict definition which doesn't mean anything).

```
transactions = []

def transaction():
  transactions.append(
    {'transaction_record':len(transactions)+1,
     'transaction_name': input('Transaction Name: '),
     'amount':float(input('Amount: ')),
     'date':'{:%A, %b %d, %Y}'.format(date.today()),
     'budget':input('Which budget? ')
    })
transaction()
```

Answer (score 1):

By putting `global transactions` inside the function, you're redefining it every time you call it, thus emptying it out.

Also, transaction_dict isn't being used; it seems like you intended it to store all the transaction_record and such, but you're just storing a dictionary that's defined on the spot, which, well, *works*, but doesn't seem like the intent.

Comment: Thank you, Putnam! This makes a lot of sense. I'm already defining the dictionary with the append function without declaring a "new dict". It also makes sense to take the global transactions bit out and update to hit the base code. I don't think these edits are helping to append without overwriting the previous issues, though.